# validations on input fields using GetOrgChart

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax, orgchart

How to apply validations on input fields using GetOrgChart? i have used the following code..

json_data = $.rails.ajax
      url: "/organization_units.json"
      async: false
      dataType: "json"

```
$("#organization").getOrgChart
  gridView: false
  zoomable: true
  printable: true
  editable: true
  color: "neutralgrey"
  primaryColumns: ["Title", "Role","Members"]
  dataSource: json_data.responseJSON.tree_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example for you, hit "Run Code Snippet" and try to update the Phone with invalid phone number.

```js
$("#people").getOrgChart({  
    primaryColumns: ["Name", "Title"],
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Title: "ESL teacher", Phone: "05454545454"},
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Title: "Bricklayer",  Phone: "08888888888"},
      { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson", Title: "Nursing aide", Phone: "077777777"}]
});   

$("#people").on("updateEvent", function( event, sender, args ) {  
   if (!/^\d+$/.test(args.data.Phone)){
    event.preventDefault();
    args.returnValue = false;
    alert(args.data.Name + ' cannot be updated because Phone number field is not in correct format!');
  } 
});
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

I have created an example for you, hit "Run Code Snippet" and try to update the Phone with invalid phone number.
 



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css">   
  
    
<script type='text/javascript' src="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>


<div id="people"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Muse VSExtensions,
  Thanks for your answer
   . It is really good for java script validations. But i am using Rails framework. I want model level validations that requires input field names. But in this case with getOrgChart it has just input tag with "value".
is there any way  to get input field name?